# Square abs of a circular complex Gaussian random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $a$ be a circular complex Gaussian random variable with mean value $\mu$ and variance 1, i.e. $a \sim \mathcal{CN}(\mu,1)$.

Which is the distribution of $|a|^2$?

Comment: what have you tried? where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I tried to use the results for 2-dimensional real Gaussian random vectors. For example, if $\mu=0$, it is easy to show that $2|a|^2 \sim \chi_2^2(0)$, where $\chi_2^2(0)$ is a central $\chi^2$ distribution with 2 degrees of freedom. The simulations agreed with this result.   
     Then, I tried to generalize this result for $\mu \in \mathbb{C} \neq 0$. So, I expected that $2|a|^2 \sim \chi_2^2(|\mu|^2)$, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Maybe I found my stupid mystake... It should be $2|a|^2 \sim \chi_2^2(2|\mu|^2)$, rigth?